# Styling PHP echo in a span and table

Tags: php, styles

Have created the following code, which includes a background image, and a skewed table. The contentes of the table are drawn from a database using PHP.

I don't have the ability to style the PHP text in the table other than changing the font, but altering the class "table". Is there a specific way of working with PHP echo text in this context to style it. I want to change the size and colour of the text.

Many thanks

```
 <div class="information_request_form">
  <img src="images/information_request_form.png" width="1051" height="1013" />
  <div class="skewed">
  <div class="table" >
  <?php 
  $array = explode(',', $_SESSION['cart']);
  echo "<span ><table width='835' border = '0'>";
  foreach($array as $cartId) {
  $ship_name = $row_ships['ship_name'];
  $ship_image = $row_ships['image'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width='110' height='58'><img src='images/ships/$ship_image'width='83' height='53' /> </td>";
  echo "<td width='620' height='58'>$ship_name</td>";
  echo "<td width='35' height='58'><a href='cart.php?action=delete&ship_id=$cartId'><img src='images/trash.png' width='31' height='42' /></a></td>";
  echo "<td height='58'>$cartId</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  } 
  echo "</table></div>";
    ?>
  </div>
  </span>
  <div class="table_email">
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td height="54" >
  <input name="email" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='enter your email address') this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = 'enter your email address'" value="enter your email address" size="50" maxlength="50">
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way would to add a class/id to the ones you want to style and add something in the CSS to accompany that.

```
echo "<td width='35' height='58' class='styled-td'><a href='cart.php?action=delete&ship_id=$cartId'>";
```

And some CSS:

```
.styled-td { color: blue; }
```